# Declaring functions as variables in c

Tags: c

I'm currently reviewing for an exam at my university and came across some puzzling code examples with regards to linked list. In the book THE ALGORITHM DESIGN MANUAL by Steven S. Skiena, he uses some interesting syntax that I don't quite understand.

```c
delete_list (list **l, item_type x)
{
    list *p;
    list *pred;
    list *search_list(), *predicessor_list();

    p = seach_list(*l, x);
    if (p != NULL)
    {
       pred = predecessor_list(*l, x);
       if (pred == NULL)
           *l = p-> next;
       else 
           pred->next = p->next;

       free (p);
    }

}
```

Is there a specific advantage or reason to declare the search_list() and predicessor_list() function rather than explicitly calling them? 
I am assuming that it has something to do with maintaining pointers but I cannot find any reference material on this.

Comment: hmm I was under the impression that it's a local forward declaration?

Comment: What do you mean, "*rather than calling them*"? Don't you mean "*in addition to calling them*"?

Comment: Yes, calling them. What I was meant to say is calling them without a prior declaration. 
I can update the code I just didn't want any trouble with copying code and whatnot.

Comment: That's some really crufty C code. Function prototypes have been standardized for 30+ years now. Even if you are looking at the first edition of that book, that came out in 1997 -- nearly a decade after they had been standardized. Why are parts of the list's API declared internally here? Also, having the top level object type that the user interacts with be an internal node of a list is pretty janky (e.g. - that's why you pass in a list **, how many items are in the list?, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are function declarations. There are two things I'd consider bad about them:

1. They lack a prototype:

   ```
   list *search_list(list *, item_type), *predecessor_list(list *, item_type);
   ```

   The prototype (here `list *, item_type` for each function) tells the compiler what type of arguments (and how many of them) the function expects. There is no reason not to provide that information in a function declaration.

   If you just say `list *search_list()`, the compiler cannot check whether calls of `search_list` pass correct arguments.
2. They are inside a function.

   There is no point in declaring a function inside a block. That doesn't make the function local; in standard C all functions are global. It just makes that declaration have local scope, which is fairly useless.

A more standard approach would be

```
list *search_list(list *, item_type);
list *predecessor_list(list *, item_type);

void delete_list (list **l, item_type x)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that I added a `void` return type since `delete_list` doesn't return any value. Omitting the return type used to be allowed in pre-1999 C, but it would default to `int`, not `void`.

Given that function prototypes became standard with the publication of ANSI C in 1989 and "implicit `int`" was removed in 1999 (with ISO 9899:1999), I'd be wary of the technical content in *The Algorithm Design Manual* (which bears a 2008 copyright notice).

Answer (score 1):

They are certainly declared somewhere.. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {

} list;

void foo() {
    //Forward Declaration:
    list* search_list(), *predecessor_list();

    //Function call:
    list* search_results = search_list(/*whatever arguments here*/);
    list* predecessor_results = predecessor_list(/*whatever arguments here*/);

    //Printing Pointers or whatever..
    printf("%p\n", search_results);
    printf("%p\n", predecessor_results);
}

list* search_list(/*whatever arguments here*/) {
    return NULL; //return a list pointer or node..
}

list* predecessor_list(/*whatever arguments here*/) {
    return NULL; //return a list pointer or node..
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

If you comment out:

```
/*list* search_list() {
    return malloc(sizeof(list));
}

list* predecessor_list() {
    return malloc(sizeof(list));
}*/
```

You will get the error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /home/J3v1L7/cc02GJDL.o: in function `foo':
>   prog.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to`search_list' /usr/bin/ld:
>   prog.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `predecessor_list'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Why? Because `list* search_list(), *predecessor_list();` is a forward declaration of the two functions `search_list` and `predecessor`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

Comment: So this is an alternative to prototyping?

Comment: The `,` in declarations is not the comma operator.

Comment: A declaration using `()` (i.e. without a prototype) does not mean "takes no arguments", it means "takes an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified types".

Comment: Well it's a separator that allows them to declare more than one on the same line in the same declaration.. I don't know how else to word it. `()` can mean BOTH.. since they didn't post any `more` of the code, I assumed it took zero arguments. Technically you are correct and it can take whatever they decide to pass later on.

Comment: `Correction:` It's literally telling the compiler.. hey there is a `prototype/function` declared somewhere that returns a `list*` and has the name `search_list` with some arguments `()`.. then there is another one, declared as returning a `list*` and named `predecessor_list` that also takes some arguments `()`. Since the two functions are declared after `foo`.. you are just telling to compiler to find them somewhere in the file using the definition you provide: `list* search_list()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

`list *search_list(), *predicessor_list();` is a local declaration for 2 functions taking an unspecified number of arguments and returning a pointer to `list` whatever that might be.

Declaring functions in a block scope is **highly** discouraged. Declaring functions without a proper prototype is sloppy too. Defining `delete_list` without a return type is obsolete as well.

From the code posted, it seems the book is outdated and provides bad advice for newbies.

The proper code should be:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int item_type;

typedef struct list {
    item_type value;
    struct list *next;
} list;

list *search_list(list *l, item_type x);
list *predecessor_list(list *l, item_type x);

void delete_list(list **l, item_type x) {
    list *p;
    list *pred;

    p = search_list(*l, x);
    if (p != NULL) {
        pred = predecessor_list(*l, x);
        if (pred == NULL)
            *l = p->next;
        else 
            pred->next = p->next;
        free (p);
    }
}
```

And of course a better version of `delete_list` would avoid a double scan:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

/* delete the first node with value x, return 1 if found, else return 0 */
int delete_list(list **pp, item_type x) {
    for (list *p = *pp; p != NULL; pp = &p->next, p = p->next) {
        if (p->value == x) {
            *pp = p->next;
            free(p);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```